# Is it possible to use Apps Script to publish existing charts in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am aware that I can just click and publish my charts in any Google Sheets but I'm seeking a solution for doing the same using Apps Script (or similar).

Right now I have a Sheets file that contains:

(1) a sheet with data (let's call it the "DATA" sheet),

(2) a sheet where I use Apps Script to clean any existing data, then select and copy data from sheet #1, and then perform operations (the "COMPUTE" sheet), and

(3) a sheet which contains 3 published charts that references the data in sheet #2 (the "DISPLAY" sheet).

The idea is to have a portal for users to key in their IDs and fetch charts based on their data. As there will be multiple users accessing at the same time, I was planning on copying a different set of "COMPUTE" and "DISPLAY" sheets to a new file for each user.

Unfortunately, even though all that worked and the charts in the new file have the same OIDs as the original ones (hence the URL referencing for display is easy to put together, e.g.,`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/pubchart?oid={OID}&format=interactive"`), they will not display until I manually publish them.

So is there a way to do it programmatically? Also, for the sake of the discussion, let's just say Google Visualisation API is not a viable solution in this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish a chart to the web with google apps script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803718/how-to-publish-a-chart-to-the-web-with-google-apps-script)